# stale element reference: element is not attached to the page, while clicking a hidden button using xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to click following button using xpath in selenium,

```
<div class="bg-iconButton-button bg-common-nodrag bg-tool-maximize bg-common-hideDisplay" title="Display in full screen" id="bg-po-full-screen-1"></div>
```

I tried the below code,

```
fullscreenbutton=UtilityFunc.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='bg-po-full-screen-1']"));
KeywordFunc.fnClick(fullscreenbutton);
```

I am getting following error,

> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

I think I am facing this issue because its enclosed as a div and not button.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can just select your element by its ID rather than its Xpath.

```
WebElement fullscreenbutton = UtilityFunc.driver.findElement(By.id("bg-po-full-screen-1"));
```

Secondly the element you're trying to click has no onClick event associated with it nor is it a button. Are you sure your actual button is not nested inside it or is below it?

Comment: Its a clickable hidden button which is visible when cursor is hovered over it. when mouse is hovered over it its class changes to "bg-iconButton-button bg-common-nodrag bg-tool-maximize bg-tool -maximizeOver"